# MSVC 2013 loading x86 system libraries in x64 build

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013

First off, I did already check and found this question which is similar to my issue:

[fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563756/fatal-error-lnk1112-module-machine-type-x64-conflicts-with-target-machine-typ/4364020#4364020)

The solution there isn't usable though as VS2013 doesn't have the VC++ Directories settings anymore. It looks like those are configured through environment variables now, but I'm not sure how to fix this without borking the 32-bit builds.

====================================

I am working on porting a project from 32-bit to 64-bit code and so I created an x64 platform in my visual studio project. The debug build works fine, but the release build give me this error:

1>MSVCRT.lib(ti_inst.obj) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

Setting the VERBOSE:Lib option, it appears to be trying to find the default system libraries in the x86 paths instead of x64. This pastebin includes the compiler and linker commandlines (yes, this is MACHINE:X64) as well as the VERBOSE:Lib output.

http://pastebin.com/Bqu0udRi

I'd like to know a) how do I fix this, and b) why would this only affect the release build? Looking at the library progress log for the debug build, I can see it is picking up the x64 paths and libraries correctly.

Comment: It would be useful if that error told you which module it was complaining about.

Comment: My guess is C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\ is not 64-bit code.  The VC++ Directories has x86 and x64 settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it affect only Release build, because you have different properties set in this build configuration or different property sheets attached.

First of all, open Visual Studio, then go to Property Manager and expand `Release | x64` configuration. Check if any other `.props` are placed above the `Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user`. If yes, check if they do not overwrite include/library directories.

Also compare what `.props` are attached in `Debug | x64` configuration. Maybe some of them are required but not attached in `Release`?

If all this is fine, verify `Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user` itself. Go again to Property Manager, right click it and then `Properties` -> `VC++ Directories`. Check if `Library Directories` entry contains something like:

```
$(VCInstallDir)lib\amd64
$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib\amd64
$(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x64)
```

The above entries are copied from my x64 `.props` file.

Lastly, switch to Solution Explorer and then check Project Properties - your project may have defined additional local directories, that are missing in this configuration (or shouldn't be present). Simply compare content in `Debug` and `Release` configurations.

Hope this helps.

**One more thing:**

You may also want to check global macros used by Visual Studio (or, to be more precise, what do they expand to). [I ran into very serious problem once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056470/visual-studio-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-kernel32-lib-only-in-wp8-proj), after (with no reason) one of standard directory macro was overwritten to wrong value.

Comment: The build configuration looks fine as far as I can tell. I included the options being used in the pastebin in my question. Looking at the properties, Release does have Whole Program Optimization but that doesn't override any directories. Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user and Upgrade from VC 6.0 property pages both show "$(VC_LibraryPath_x64);$(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x64);" as the library paths. Those macros seem to point to the right locations.

Comment: Actually even though all the pages look fine, something was overriding the Release|x64 directories in the properties. Everything works now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I don't work with VS a lot and didn't realize all this was in the property manager.